# Is it possible to use Digest Auth with Fetch in React Native?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, digest-authentication

I am wondering if it is possible to use digest auth as headers together with Fetch in React Native? Or, are there any other alternatives? I have tried the following:

```
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Digest " + ("username:password"));
  return fetch(`url`,{
  headers: {
  headers,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
 })
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log("checked if on local server response")

  return responseJson;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('checked if on local server response error')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an external module that works for RN:
https://github.com/besing/digest-auth-request-rn

This worked fine for me on Android but I had to make some local changes to get it working on iOS. I'll submit those modifications for you to benefit from.

Comment: I would benefit from it greatly :) so if you could post your code it would be greate